# Finding the journey made by users in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking to find the journey made by users on a particular website. The schema of my dataset is the same as Google Merchandise Store, which can be found here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

From the Google BigQuery cookbook, I've implemented and modified the SQL code provided to get the sequence of hits made by every customer.

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId AS id,
  visitId AS visitid,
  visitNumber AS visitnumber,
  h.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
  CASE
    WHEN h.eventInfo.eventAction = "Lead" THEN "Lead"
    WHEN h.eventInfo.eventAction = "Homepage" THEN "Homepage"
    WHEN h.eventInfo.eventAction = "Search" THEN "Search"
    WHEN h.eventInfo.eventAction = "High Intent Use" THEN "High Intent Use"
    WHEN h.eventInfo.eventAction = "Listing Page" THEN "Listing Page"
  END AS journey
FROM
  `dataset`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS h
WHERE
  h.type="PAGE"
  OR h.type="EVENT"
ORDER BY
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  visitNumber,
  hitNumber
```

A snippet of the result I got is as follows:

```
fullVisitorId visitId visitNumber hitnumber  journey
    001        1001       1           1      Homepage
    001        1001       1           2      Search
    001        1001       1           3      null
    001        1001       1           4      Search
    001        1001       1           5      Listing Page
    001        1001       1           6      Lead
    001        1001       1           2      Search
    001        1001       1           7      Lead
    002        1002       1           1      Search
    ...
```

What I need is to get another column which shows the journey taken by each visitor before the first "Lead", while ignoring the duplicates (for eg if the visitor searches for 5 pages back-to-back, the journey should only show "Search" once)
ie. for visitor 001 on visit 1001, the column will show:

```
Homepage -> Search -> Listing Page -> Lead
```

I hope the question is clear. Appreciate any help given! :)

Comment: This is a similar Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196418/finding-the-customer-journey-channels-made-by-users-in-google-bigquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below  is for BigQuery Standard SQL and applies extra logic to your existing/current query

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  fullVisitorId, visitId, 
  STRING_AGG(journey, ' -> ' ORDER BY visitNumber, hitnumber) journey_path
FROM (
  SELECT 
    fullVisitorId, visitId, 
    MIN(visitNumber) visitNumber, MIN(hitnumber) hitnumber, journey
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNTIF(journey = 'Lead') OVER(win) grp
    FROM `your_current_query`
    WINDOW win AS (
      PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitId 
      ORDER BY visitNumber, hitnumber 
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    )
  )
  WHERE grp = 0
  GROUP BY fullVisitorId, visitId, journey
)
GROUP BY fullVisitorId, visitId
```

so you can just use your existing query as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `your_current_query` AS (
  SELECT
    fullVisitorId AS id,
    visitId AS visitid,
    visitNumber AS visitnumber,
    h.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
    CASE
      WHEN h.eventInfo.eventAction = "Lead" THEN "Lead"
      WHEN h.eventInfo.eventAction = "Homepage" THEN "Homepage"
      WHEN h.eventInfo.eventAction = "Search" THEN "Search"
      WHEN h.eventInfo.eventAction = "High Intent Use" THEN "High Intent Use"
      WHEN h.eventInfo.eventAction = "Listing Page" THEN "Listing Page"
    END AS journey
  FROM
    `dataset`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS h
  WHERE
    h.type="PAGE"
    OR h.type="EVENT"
)
SELECT 
  fullVisitorId, visitId, 
  STRING_AGG(journey, ' -> ' ORDER BY visitNumber, hitnumber) journey_path
FROM (
  SELECT 
    fullVisitorId, visitId, 
    MIN(visitNumber) visitNumber, MIN(hitnumber) hitnumber, journey
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNTIF(journey = 'Lead') OVER(win) grp
    FROM `your_current_query`
    WINDOW win AS (
      PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitId 
      ORDER BY visitNumber, hitnumber 
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    )
  )
  WHERE grp = 0
  GROUP BY fullVisitorId, visitId, journey
)
GROUP BY fullVisitorId, visitId
--- ORDER BY fullVisitorId, visitId
```

and if to follow your result example - above should produce below result

```
Row fullVisitorId   visitId     journey_path     
1   001             1001        Homepage -> Search -> Listing Page -> Lead   
2   002             1002        Search
```

Comment: Hi @mikhail, thank you for your answer! Can you explain what 'COUNTIF(journey = 'Lead') OVER(win) grp' does and why did you filter 'grp = 0'?

Comment: Ahh okay, I played around with the query and I figured out that 'grp = 0' captures all the hits before the first lead. Always learning something new from you @Mikhail! Thank you :)

Comment: sure. correct. this is to group all events before each "lead". as you wanted to have only events before first lead -  'grp = 0' did exactly that. glad you got this by yourself :o)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [STRING_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg) to make a string of the journey steps, adding DISTINCT into your selection will only show individual journey steps once per user.

[image]

Something like:

`STRING_AGG(DISTINCT(journey), '->') as propensity_banding_subset`

You could then use some regex to clip off after the first 'lead', unless somebody can suggest a better method to do this in the original string aggregation?

Comment: ahhhh thanks @Ben, this helped bring me to the next step! :) I am thinking of combining strpos() with other functions (possibly substr()) to do the clipping. Will update here again if I manage to get the result.

Comment: `STRING_AGG` in conjunction with `DISTINCT` does not guarantee a correct order: with `DISTINCT` you can only `ORDER BY journey` - not by `hitNumber` - but without `ORDER BY` no order is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

I took Mikhails great approach and brought it to a more scalable version for those who have really large amounts of data. The idea is the same, but applied to a subquery on the hits array.

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId AS id,
  visitId AS visitid,
  visitNumber AS visitnumber,
  ARRAY(
   (SELECT AS STRUCT * 
    FROM 
      (SELECT AS STRUCT
         hitNumber,
         page.pagePath, -- pagePath instead of CASE-WHEN with events
         count(page.pagePath) over (win) elNumber
       FROM t.hits 
       WHERE type IN ('PAGE', 'EVENT') 
       WINDOW win AS (
        PARTITION BY page.pagePath
        ORDER BY hitnumber 
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
        )
       ORDER BY hitNumber)
    WHERE elNumber=0
      -- instead of 'Lead' I used '/signin.html' 
      AND hitNumber < (SELECT MIN(hitNumber) FROM t.hits WHERE page.pagePath='/signin.html')
    )
  ) AS journey
FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` t
limit 1000
```

I used the actual sample data and couldn't find the events from the example there so I simply used page paths. But it should be easily adoptable.

Also this one returns nested data, not a flat table, which again saves space when saving the result as a table and is faster when performing queries on it.

There is also no grouping involved - everything happens within the subquery only on the array which allows very fast processing due to parallization.