# Finding the Customer journey (channels) made by users in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, attribution

I'm looking to find the Customer Journey user's made via the Online Marketing Channels. The schema of my dataset is the same as Google Merchandise Store, which can be found here: 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

This is how my input data looks like (example):

```
+---------------+-------+------------+---------+--------------+-------------+
| fullVisitorId | visit | visitTime  | revenue | transactions |   channel   |
+---------------+-------+------------+---------+--------------+-------------+
|          1234 |     1 | 1516468217 | null    | null         | Direct      |
|          1234 |     2 | 1517937012 | null    | null         | EMail       |
|          1234 |     3 | 1523031014 | null    | null         | Organic     |
|          1234 |     4 | 1530461419 | null    | null         | Organic     |
|          1234 |     5 | 1531152611 | null    | null         | Paid Search |
|          1234 |     6 | 1531411812 | 1393000 | 1            | Organic     |
+---------------+-------+------------+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

I already did this SQL Query:

```
WITH
_step1 AS (SELECT
DISTINCT
a.fullVisitorId, 
a.visitNumber,
a.visitStartTime,
a.Date,
a.totals.totalTransactionRevenue AS totalTransactionRevenue,
a.totals.transactions AS transactions,
a.channelGrouping AS channelGrouping

FROM
`data` a,
unnest(a.hits) as h
)
SELECT
a.fullVisitorId as visitor,
STRING_AGG(channelGrouping, '>') AS CustomerJourney, 
SUM(totalTransactionRevenue) AS Umsatz, 
SUM(transactions) AS transaktionen
FROM
_step1 as s

GROUP BY fullVisitorId
```

The results should look like:

```
+--------+----------------------------+---------+---------------+
| visitor| CustomerJourney            | Umsatz  | transaktionen |
+--------+----------------------------+---------+---------------+
|1234    | Direct>EMail               | null    | null          |
|1234    | Organic                    | null    | null          |
|1234    | Organic>Paid Search>Organic| 1393000 | 1             |
+--------+----------------------------+---------+---------------+
```

What i actually get:

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
| visitor| CustomerJourney                                 | Umsatz  | transaktionen |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
|1234    | Direct>EMail>Organic>Organic>Paid Search>Organic|1393000  |1              |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+
```

The difficult part:

There is a conversion tracking period (30 days), which means that a new customer journey will start if 30 days have elapsed since the first visit or if the user has completed a transaction (a new Row).
There are Timestamps for every visit.

**Which query must I start to consider the conversion tracking period?**

Comment: Yes my code does not consider any tracking period. My data includes a full year. I don't know how to implement this '30 Days Period'.

Comment: Maybe just have `a.visitStartTime > '2018-12-01'`  (or whatever date you consider a "30 days period") ? Or do you want to have a different definition of "30 days period"? Maybe show examples of stuff that constitutes a 30 days period, and other examples of stuff that is no 30 days period.

Comment: There are two cases: 
Case one: 
Imagine a customer visit my Website for the first time on 10.01.2018.
For the next 30 Days (30 days conversion tracking period) i track all the touchpoint he made via my marketing-touchpoints. After this 30 days the customer journey ends and a new CJ starts (that means a new row as CJ). For example he comes again on 15.02.2018 -> new CJ -> new row.
Case two:
Imagine a customer visit my Website. After 7 days he does a transaktion -> CJ ends and a new CJ begins if he come back after the Transaktion.
->This is for every single User.

Comment: Can you please add examples of these rows, and of the results you think you should get to your question? From your description, I still don't see how a simple `where` clause on the visit start time doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: The expected rows looks like the rows i already have in the description above (but there i didn't respected the 30 days period).
I don't have an specific starttime because a customer journey could start anytime.
-> I want every CJ from every user in the year 2018 (no specific one from one user)

Comment: Yes, but I still don't see what input data you have. It's hard for me to understand where you want to get if I don't see where you're coming from. Please [edit] your post and add some exemplary source rows and explain why these rows should/shouldn't be included in the result.

Comment: I edited the data. I hope it is easier to understand now. The unix-date in the first two rows are 20/01/2018 and  06/01/2018. Third is 06/04/2018 and the last three are all in Jule 2018.